# Numbering in Word 2016 is always in English, even for Arabic documents

Tags: microsoft-word, language, microsoft-word-2016

I have a problem with numbered lists in Word 2016, no matter what the text is, the numbered lists is always in English.

It's only transformed to Arabic when I make the numerals "Hindi", but this is not a suitable solution because sometimes I have English and Arabic numbers in the same document.

Comment: There are no "English" numbers. The normal numerals are [Arabic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals). You would need to be more specific with what you actually mean. You could always [define your own list style](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-bulleted-or-numbered-list-9FF81241-58A8-4D88-8D8C-ACAB3006A23E) which uses whatever symbols you need. If it's not in the selection for the kind of symbols you use and it's not countable you probably would need to add the number yourself.

Comment: Nah, your are missing something here - He's talking modern arabic numerals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Arabic_mathematical_notation while we use hindu-arabic numerals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals - Further complicated by 3 different classes of (modern) arabic numerals

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post:](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10/numbering-in-arabic-document-in-word-2016-for/9c2c3170-e247-49e5-8489-3ff112218a6c)

The context numbering issue is now fixed for both Arabic and Persian n build 16.0.7369.2024, released on 10/4. To get the latest updates, click File> Account > Update Options > Update Now.

Have you ran your updates all the way through yet?

Comment: Furthermore, the solution to the problem of having separate types of numerals in the same document can be found here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-different-page-numbers-or-number-formats-to-different-sections-in-Word-2016-for-Mac-35e1d683-40e7-4b6a-b0a3-79893d6485de